Subdividing Font Space in the Terminal for High-Definition Pixel Art
I just started programming as a hobby three weeks ago, and I'm amazed at what I can do. I exclusively use Rust.
Before I try making a game with a GUI, I want to create a simple one in the terminal. However, I plan to incorporate Pixel Art for context in that game.
I've seen some ways to display pictures in the terminal, but since I'm limited to a font size, I specifically want to try displaying 4x8 pixels within each font space. This means, for example, a 120x120 pixel art would appear in a 30x15 font space.
I don't want to use average colors; I want the authentic picture to be displayed.
I tryed a method that can divide a font space in 2 (1x2) but:

It's not exactly good enough
It use average colors so there is no detail.

use image::GenericImageView;
use crossterm::{terminal::{self, ClearType}, ExecutableCommand};
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

// Function to get the average color of a sub-region
fn average_color(img: &image::DynamicImage, x_start: u32, y_start: u32, width: u32, height: u32) -> [u8; 3] {
    let mut r_sum = 0;
    let mut g_sum = 0;
    let mut b_sum = 0;
    let mut count = 0;

    for y in y_start..y_start + height {
        for x in x_start..x_start + width {
            let pixel = img.get_pixel(x, y);
            let [r, g, b, _] = pixel.0;
            r_sum += r as u32;
            g_sum += g as u32;
            b_sum += b as u32;
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    [
        (r_sum / count) as u8,
        (g_sum / count) as u8,
        (b_sum / count) as u8,
    ]
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Load the image
    let img = image::open("path_to_file.jpg")?;
    let (width, height) = img.dimensions();
    
    // Check the size of the image
    if width != 54 || height != 54 {
        eprintln!("L'image doit être de taille 50x50 !");
        return Ok(());
    }

    // Initialize the terminal
    let mut stdout = stdout();
    terminal::enable_raw_mode()?;
    stdout.execute(terminal::Clear(ClearType::All))?;

    // Define the size of each sub-region
    let sub_width = 1;
    let sub_height = 2;

    // Display each pixel
    for y in (0..height).step_by(sub_height as usize) {
        for x in (0..width).step_by(sub_width as usize) {
            // Get the average color for the top half of the character cell
            let top_color = average_color(&img, x, y, sub_width, sub_height);

            // Get the average color for the bottom half of the character cell
            let bottom_color = average_color(&img, x, y + sub_height / 2, sub_width, sub_height / 2);

            // Print the top half color
            print!("\x1b[38;2;{};{};{}m\x1b[48;2;{};{};{}m▀", bottom_color[0], bottom_color[1], bottom_color[2], top_color[0], top_color[1], top_color[2]);
        }
        // Move to the next line
        print!("\x1b[0m\r\n");
    }

    // Reset colors
    print!("\x1b[0m");
    stdout.flush()?;
    
    // Keep the terminal open until a key is pressed
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut String::new())?;

    // Disable raw mode in the terminal
    terminal::disable_raw_mode()?;

    Ok(())
}


If that matter, I use Linux.
I'm not sure if I'm asking too much, so thank you for your help.

A simple Google search reveals viuer which looks like a good library. However it isn't clear to me why you don't want to use real graphics.

As written this question is not really suited for SO. Since you already have attempted a method, post your code and describe why it doesn't work ("It's not exactly good enough" is very vague).

@user2407038 Edited

@ChayimFriedman Viuer don't do what I want it to to, each font space must have 4x8 pixels.

Why not? If you will adjust the width and height correctly, it will be however you want (also, it supports perfect rendering with sixel if supported by the terminal).
